# parameters are not removing scope issue in screens using primefaces

Tags: jakarta-ee, jsf-2, primefaces

i am using jsf2.0.i have a Menu.Each menu has a default screen that is custom search screen. Multiple search parameter fields have been given there to search (like search by item, search by doc).I have used session scoped managed bean

```
   @ManagedBean(name="bbItemManager")
    @SessionScoped
    public class BbItemManager {
    //search parameters
    private String byItem;
    private String byDoc;
    //view paramters
    private List<Users> list;
    private List<Items> items;
    //taransactions screen paramters
    private String itemName;
    private String DocName;
    private String saveButton="false";
    private String updateButton="true";
    //all screens mothods here
    //all paramters setters getters here
    }
```

This one backing bean controls custom search(on default search screen) as well as two another sceens(transactional and view) with this one backing bean "bbItemManager".

`issue`: searching paramters values(on default search screen) remain same(not refreshed) as i am going to interact with another screen through menu as soon as i come back to previous used screen the searched parameter remain same.

```
what should be there?
```

The Default screen reloads and refresh all paramters. also i don not want to remove

```
@sessionScope
```

from backing bean as it is also used by transactional and view sreens which require it.
please give any solution as i solve this issue.

Comment: The solution is not using `@SessionScoped` for view matters. Use `@ViewScoped` for search-result related views.

Comment: @Xtreme:but two other screens(transactional and view) needs @ SessionScope.what should i do at this situation

Comment: Always split the session and view stuffs. If a variable is going to be used only in a specific view (doesn't maintain the state along the session) stick to view scope. There's no problem to access session and view scoped beans from the views using EL and if you also need to reference the session bean from a view bean, you can always inject it as a `@ManagedProperty`.

Comment: @Xtreme then how to inject it with @ManagedProperty?

Comment: http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/injecting-managed-beans-in-jsf-2-0/